# S5 Accordion Menu ( Mootools) changes

Tags: joomla, mootools, accordion

I'm using S5 Accordion Menu on my Joomla site.

http://jalousie.al-soft.ru/o-programme

What I need is to make it not slide down, when I reload page. It needs to work like accordion only when you click on it items, but not when the page reloads.

However it will be great, if it will be possible to save its open state for current page, but without accordion effect when page loads, just load it opened.

Sorry for my english. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Here is the source

http://jalousie.al-soft.ru/modules/mod_s5_accordion_menu/js/s5_accordion_menu.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the Accordion class that ships with [mootols/more/FX](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Accordion) just use the initialDisplayFx option to disable the initial animation. Something like the following code should work.

```
var s5_accordion_menu = new Accordion($('s5_accordion_menu'), 
     'h3.s5_am_toggler', 
     'div.s5_accordion_menu_element', {
          opacity: true,
          allowMultipleOpen: true,
          display: s5_am_openElement,
          alwaysHide: true,
          initialDisplayFx: false
     });
```

The signature of the class you use does not match the "official" one but maybe it is just a wrapper otherwise the answer is not, you can't disable the effect